# Set up run as automatic for task scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

I am trying to set account for task scheduler as "automatic" means instead of providing my credentials during creating a task scheduler in 'run as' window
it should be run as per pre specified schedule as automatic (for windows server 2003 R2 version)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by automatic but if you want the task to run without your credentials you can enter NT Authority\SYSTEM for the username and leave the password blank.  The task will run with local administrator rights.

[image]